# Is there a way to cast a generic list / dictionary to any implemented interfaces of the containing objects

Tags: c#, generics, casting

Is there a way to cast a generic collection to any of the interfaces being implemented by the stored objects ?

So the idea would be to have the possibly to expose the underlying dictionary or list via a cast only through the interface definitions of the underlying stored objects. In case of the List it seems to be possible by using IEnumerable or IReadonlyList, but what about dictionaries ?

```
public interface IMyClass
{
 ...
}

public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
  ...
}

public class AccessClass
{
    List<MyClass> _list = new List<MyClass>();
    Dictionary<string, MyClass>  _dic = new Dictionary<string, MyClass>();
    public IList<IMyClass> ObjectList
    {
    // is there a way to achieve a cast like this ? 
    get {
        return _list as IList<MyClassInterface>;
    }

    public IDictionary<string, IMyClass> ObjectDict
    get {
    // is there a way to achieve this as well ?
        return _dic as IDictionary<string, IMyClass>;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you *have* to use `IList<T>` rather than `IEnumerable<T>`? You could already return `IEnumerable<IMyClass>` due to generic variance.

Comment: @JonSkeet : okay, that would be one possibility. But IEnumerable does not have indexed access I think. And same question would also occur when I use Dictionary<T1, T2> .

Comment: `IReadOnlyList<T>` would be an option with indexed access. But for dictionaries I don't know of a good option, as `IReadOnlyDictionary<,>` is invariant.

Comment: @JonSkeet: sounds interesting and is helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

(As noted in comments...)

The reason you can't do this with `List<T>` is that it's *invariant* - as are all classes. Only delegates and interfaces support *generic covariance* which is what you want here.

If the callers to `AccessClass` only need to read entries, you could just change your property to be of type `IReadOnlyList<T>`, which is covariant in `T`.

```cs
public IReadOnlyList<IMyClass> ObjectList => _list;
```

If the callers need *write* access to the list, you have bigger problems anyway, because you need to think about what would happen with something like:

```
access.ObjectList.Add(new SomeOtherIMyClassImplementation());
```

In comments you asked about `Dictionary<,>` - unfortunately I don't know of any convariant dictionary type. You could potentially create your own wrapper type implementing an interface that you define yourself, but it wouldn't be terribly idioimatic.

Comment: That would clearly solve the problem for generic lists in most cases. If would be really interesting whether there exists a similar approach for dictionaries...

Comment: @FlorianStorck: Was just adding a note to say that I don't believe there is such a thing.